# How to keep both released and updated APK?

Tags: android, debugging, google-play, android-debug

After downloading my app from the Play Store I tried to run it from Android Studio
but got this error..

[image]

Is there a simple way to keep both apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is the problem**

There is conflict between your production APK and your debug APK.

The debug APK (installed by Android Studio) is signed using the `debug.keystore` (keystore).
The production APK is signed using one you created, with a passphrase only known by you.

So the device refuses to replace an application by another one claiming to be the same (same `packageName`) but that has a different signature (eg: has not been signed using your passphrase, so potentially not by you -- the author).

**How to solve it**

You now have two choices:

1. You want to have both applications side by side, then use another `packageName` for debug. This is easily done using Gradle:

```
android {
    // ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            // ...
        }
        release {
            // applicationIdSuffix
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

2. You want to keep only one application at a time: you just need to remove the old application to install the new one (with another signature).

Comment: Thank you it works. do I have to remove         debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'

        } before uploading to the playstore?

Comment: No, because you won't be uploading a debug APK.

Comment: Oh so If I understood correctly, Android Studio is using the "release" build type automatically every time I do Build>Generate Singed APK, and if I just run it normally it's using the "debug" build type?

Answer (score 0):

just change the **package name** of application until you finish your editing

Answer (score 0):

### Reason why you are getting this error

Anytime you try to install an application with the same package name of any application installed in your device, you get this error.

### Solution

Try to modify your package name of application in your current Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to modify android studio to sign your apk with the release keystore in debug as well, although thats generally not recommended.
That way when you install either apk you will keep your data.

Only problem is that both apks must be at the same versions to be interchangeable (you will not be able to install a lower version apk, at least not easily).